# XPath expression for containing element of a given text node

Tags: xml, xpath

I am coding some Perl to use XPath to locate a particular `td` element within a table` that looks similar to this

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td><font color="white" face="verdana, Helvetica, Arial" size="2">Showing <b>1</b>-<b>100</b> of <b>200</b> total</font></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

What I want is to find a `td` element that has a `font/text()` node that contains the string `Showing`.

matches `contains(., "Showing")`

A direct comparison works fine:

```
//td[font/text()="Showing "]
```

but I want to use the `contains()` XPath function so that the match is more flexible.

I have tried

```
//td[contains(font/text(), "Showing ")]
```

but this raises the error

```
XPath failed due to: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains()
```

and I have managed to achieve what I want with

```
//td[font/text()[contains(., "Showing")]]
```

but this is very ugly and I am hoping for something more concise. Please can someone improve on this for me, or perhaps confirm that this is the best and most concise way?

Comment: More concise? You have an xpath that says "All `td`s that have a `font` whose text contains `Showing`" - which is exactly your problem statement! - and you want it to be more concise?!

Comment: @AakashM: Yes I do. Just because it is *one* way to express what I want doesn't mean it's the *cleanest*. I don't have to write `//td[font/text()[.="Showing "]]` so I thought there may be a way using `contains` instead of `=`.

Comment: So why do you think the expression is "very ugly"? It is the one I would use -- and this means that at least to my knowledge, there isn't a more elegant one.

Comment: XPath 2.0 allows one to specify a more elegant expression that selects the same nodes. Do you want an XPath 2.0 answer?

Comment: Correction: Even in XPath 2.0 the one you are using is the most ellegant. It isn't meaningful to replace `contains()` with Regex, and the expression `//td[some $t in font/text() satisfies contains($t, 'Showing')]` compared to yours seems "stupidly verbose" to me.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
//td[contains(font/text()[1], 'Showing ')]
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill. That works, but only if it is the first text node that matches. I want to find a `td` where any `font/text()` contains the given string.

Comment: @Borodin You mean like this: `//td[contains(font/text(), 'Showing ')]`   ?

Comment: @Borodin, According to XPath spec, if an argument is not of type `string`, it is first converted to a string using the `string()` function and then the result of that conversion is evaluated. So your XPath engine doesn't work properly.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: Borodin is right -- the XPath expression in this answer fails to select a `td` where `contains(font/text()[2], 'Showing')` is `true()`, but `contains(font/text()[1], 'Showing')` is `false()`